# "How many of them boys is/are witcha' ..."

Tags: singular-vs-plural

[a rap song](https://genius.com/50-cent-hate-it-or-love-it-g-unit-remix-lyrics):
**(1)** *How many of them boys **is** witcha'

When you had that little TV you had to hit on to get a picture*

My variant:
**(2)** *How many of them boys **are** witcha'*

Why is (1) correct? I thought only (2) was correct.
What is the difference between (1) and (2)?

Comment: Many rap songs don’t use proper grammar.

Comment: @Timinycricket - many, most, or all? I am trying to imagine a rap by Charles Dickens (I may develop this!).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about decoding a rap song.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey If the singer put "_is_" instead of "_are_", therefore, he saw a semantic difference between these variants. Asking this question, I hoped someone would explain to me what this difference is in.

Comment: Do not assume that singers or writers of rap songs 'see semantic differences'.

Comment: @Timinycricket  A lot of rappers also use AAVE, in which *is* is always the conjugation for *to be* in the present tense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference between *how many of those boys are with you* and *how many of them boys is witcha* is purely a difference in dialect.

Much American rap is written in a dialect that is not General/Standard American English (the kind of English you learn in school).  As a primarily Black art form, rap tends to be written in a dialect (or dialects) that some people call African American Vernacular English (AAVE).

AAVE, like other "non-standard", or more aptly, "non-prestige" dialects, has a reputation for being uneducated speech.  There's a presumption that prestige dialects are correct and non-prestige dialects are incorrect, and that the reason people speak "incorrectly" (speak a non-prestige dialect) is that they haven't learned to speak correctly.  This is about as preposterous as suggesting that a Japanese person who speaks Japanese and not English is uneducated, or speaks incorrectly.

In fact, AAVE is not sloppy, lazy, uneducated speech; its speakers don't have a disregard for grammar rules.  They use a different set of rules.

For example, "them boys" instead of "those boys", is an example of a common feature of AAVE, which is known as [*demonstrative them*](https://ygdp.yale.edu/phenomena/demonstrative-them).

As to "them boys is" instead of "them boys are", AAVE has different rules for subject-verb agreement:

> AAVE is much like the vast majority of other vernacular varieties of English in its use of *be* leveling; in the present tense, *are*
> and *am* level to *is*, as in *The folks is home* or *Y’all is here*, while past tense be levels to *was*, as in *The folks was there* or *Y’all was here*. Past tense be leveling is much more common than present tense leveling in AAVE, as it is in virtually all varieties of vernacular English having *be* regularization. The comparison of leveling over time and place indicates that the incidence of *be* leveling is diminishing somewhat (Wolfram and Thomas 2002), probably due to the effect of prescriptive norms. Nonetheless, *be* leveling, particularly with past tense, remains an integral and robust pattern within urban AAVE.

[The grammar of urban African American Vernacular
English](https://faculty.winthrop.edu/kosterj/ENGL507/assignments/WolframUrban_AAE.pdf)

In simpler terms, some dialects of English conjugate *be* like this:

| Past | Present |
| --- | --- |
| I was | I am |
| You were | You are |
| She was | She is |
| We were | We are |
| You were | You are |
| They were | They are |

But AAVE looks like this<sup>1</sup>:

| Past | Present |
| --- | --- |
| I was | I is |
| You was | You is |
| She was | She is |
| We was | We is |
| You was | You is |
| They was | They is |

So, to answer your questions very simply:

Version 1 is correct because the lyrics are in AAVE, and in this dialect the third-person-plural form of *be* is *is*, and because this dialect uses *them* where other dialects would use *those*.

Version 2, as James K points out, is also not "standard".  Actually, "them boys are" is also correct AAVE. As Wolfram points out (17), *be* leveling in the present tense is becoming less common in some varieties of AAVE.  The Yale "demonstrative them" article quotes Brandon Philips, a Black man born in 1981, "**Them** guys **are** like..."

---

1. This is actually a pretty bad oversimplification.  For example, AAVE features copula absence:

| GAE | AAVE |
| --- | --- |
| She is happy | She happy |

And it has a different tense system, which includes things like *habitual be*:

| GAE | AAVE |
| --- | --- |
| She usually works on Tuesdays | She be working Tuesdays |

In other words, that *be* conjugation table expresses a basic idea about *be* leveling, but don't use it if you're trying to figure out how to say something in AAVE.  You can't replace General American "you are" with "you is" and necessarily expect you've made the correct AAVE phrase.

2. "Them boys is" could, in a different context, be Appalachian English, which also features the same *be* leveling and *demonstrative them* as AAVE.

3. Are there any dialects that include *demonstrative them*, but not *be* leveling?  Apparently so.  That Yale article includes a quotation from

Answer (score 2):

In standard "textbook" English, neither is correct and both would lose you marks in an IELTS exam or similar. The use of "them" as a determiner is non-standard. The contraction of "with you" to "witcha" is unacceptable in formal English.

As for the verb, in standard English, the verb must be "are".

> How many of those boys are with you?